# Heroku does not install psycopg2 from Pipfile

Tags: python, heroku, psycopg2, heroku-postgres

I have a very simple Flask Python app with this [Pipfile](https://github.com/jeschkies/tickets/blob/master/Pipfile). The Pipfile includes `"psycopg2" = "*"`. The app can conntect to the PostgreSQL database when started locally. However it fails on Heroku. It seems Heroku does not install `psycopg2` for whatever reasons. I've catpured the logs from a Heroku deployment [here](https://gist.github.com/jeschkies/3203e50cf62ddebfe619e1681ec4a0f0).

Would anyone know where to look first?
Should I rather switched back to a requirements file? Also, why is `yapf` installed when it's a dev dependency?

Comment: Did you update your `Pipfile.lock` with `pipenv lock`, commit that change, and push it to Heroku?

Comment: Yes. I even tried without the lockfile. `Pipfile.lock` mentions `psycopg2` with the correct version.

Comment: I've also purge the Heroku cache of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Heroku build output shows requirements being installed from `requirements.txt` and makes no mention of `Pipfile` or `Pipfile.lock`. It isn't clear from Heroku's documentation, but I suspect that `requirements.txt` takes precedence over `Pipfile` / `Pipfile.lock` if both are present.

Remove your `requirements.txt` file, commit the change, and push back to Heroku, e.g.

```
git rm requirements.txt
git commit -m "Remove obsolete requirements.txt"
git push heroku
```

Note that this also explains why `yapf` is being installed: it's in [your `requirements.txt` file](https://github.com/jeschkies/tickets/blob/master/requirements.txt).